# change opened link color with JS & CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

Good day, i want to change opened link color. Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
a {color: #fff; font-size: 19px; padding-right:25px;    
 }     
a:link {color: #fff;            
 }     
a:visited {
 }     
 a:hover {  color: #000;     

}     
 a:active { color: #000;
}     

.active {color:#000;}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("a.nav1").click(function () {
          // switch all tabs off
          $(".active").removeClass("active");
          // switch this tab on
          $(this).addClass("active");
       });
    });
```

**Link example**

```
<li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#home" id="link-home"href="#home">Home</a></li>
```

This work but `padding-right:25px;` reorganize my slideshow. I need to use it with `#navigation`

```
#navigation a {color: #fff; font-size: 19px;     padding-right:25px;    
 }     
#navigation a:link {color: #fff;            
 }     
#navigation a:visited {
 }     
#navigation a:hover {   color: #000;     

}     
#navigation a:active {  color: #000;
}     

.active {color:#000;}
```

But when i use `#navigation` JS script do not change color opened link to black. If i miss out `#navigation a` and use only `#navigation a link, ...` default color of links is violet (no color defined in `#navigation a:link` ).

I tried to change opened link color with

```
 .currentLink {
       color: #640200;
       background-color: #000000;
    }
```

It does not work.

Comment: Could you try and reword what you are trying to do?

Comment: `$("#navigation li a").click(function() { $(this).addClass("active").siblings('li a').removeClass("active"); });`

Comment: So, what/where is `#navigation` in the code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

`#navigation a:active {  color: #000; }`

to

`#navigation a.active {  color: #000; }`